# Changing description after a for cycle in tqdm

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

Is it possible to set the description of a `tqdm` progress bar out of its for loop?

A simple example:

```
with tqdm(range(100), desc='processing') as pbar:
    x = 0
    for i in pbar:
        x += i
    y = x ** 2
    # 3. set description of pbar 'y = {}'.format(y)'
```

What should I put in place of `3.`?

EDIT: More precisely, I want to compute `y` after having executed the for loop entirely, then I want to log the `y` value in the progress bar description (replacing the `'processing'` description).

Answer (score 15):

You may have a slight misunderstanding with how tqdm works. There is a simple inbuit command `set_description()`, to set the description for the tqdm progress bar as its looping. In your example code if you try setting the description where you have your comment nothing would happen as you have already finished looping over pbar. (though that may just be due to incorrect indentation)

Here is a simple example that shows how the description changes -

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

pbar = tqdm(range(100), desc='description')

x = 0
for i in pbar:
    x += i
    y = x**2
    pbar.set_description("y = %d" % y)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This will allow you to see how the description changes over each loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however the example I've proposed is what I want to achieve. In particular, I want to compute `y` after having executed the for loop entirely. Consequently, I want to log the `y` value in the progress bar description

Comment: @aretor as my code is right now, the description of the progress bar will have the final value of y at the end of the loop. Just remove the `time.sleep(0.5)` so it runs faster and you can test it out. I left it in so you can see how `y` changes over each iteration

Comment: I see what you mean. So basically there is no other way but computing `y` inside the for loop?

Comment: @aretor you could always print `y` after the loop was done, how imperative is it to have the description changed at the end ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the normal `print` is not an option in my as it would mess with the other next progress bars I am using in my code. In my case, it is not imperative and I think I can deal the extra computation at each step.

Comment: @aretor use `tqdm.write()` instead of print to make it not mess with your other progress bars, Ill see if I can figure out a method to change the description after the progress bar is closed but no guarantees

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208246/discussion-between-karan-shishoo-and-aretor).